# VPAID JavaScript Creatives

Tags: javascript, html, vast, double-click-advertising, vpaid

We are working with VAST 3.0 ads for ages. Recently we started receiving VPAID JavaScript creatives instead of XML VAST.

We are okay to add the support VPAID in the platform native player: Our understanding was that platform native player should implement the interface to communicate with the VPAID JavaScript creatives, but when we checked downloaded VPAID JavaScript ad code we found that it comes with its own player (i.e. `video` element).

Why is that? Is it expected that HTML5 `video` element plays the ad instead of ad being rendered in the platform native player?

Anybody can explain that to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is to enable VPAID ads to function independently from the video player. By including a video player within the creative, the ads can then be served into normal HTML ad-slots, as well as video players.

Whilst it shouldn't really be done and makes the user experience horrible, the advertising world is a pretty dirty place and you obviously get a lot more money for a preroll impression. I always used to see video ads within the 300x250 MPU ad slots, though it does seem less common now.

My local news site - https://www.bristolpost.co.uk has a good example- just scroll right to the bottom of the page and you will see a sticky ad appear, which is a preroll video.